# Create & Join Channel in Hyperledger Fabric Build your First Network Walk Through

Tags: docker, x509certificate, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying create a channel according to documentation

[Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 docs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html?highlight=create%20channel)
Have an issue with certificate. On the docker "hyperledger/fabric-tools" node I can find certificate with current name - `tlsca.example.com`. But the channel cannot be created. I have certificate hand shake issue. Should I check/mount certificate to the peer node ?

```
root@4b6423da537b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

> 2017-07-27 16:49:58.949 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
>       2017-07-27 16:49:58.949 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
>       2017-07-27 16:49:58.954 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 003 Failed to dial orderer.example.com:7050: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"x509: ECDSA verification failure\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"tlsca.example.com\")"; please retry.
>       Error: Error connecting due to  rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of \"x509: ECDSA verification failure\" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate \"tlsca.example.com\")"
>       Usage:

Thanks.

Comment: It's not very clear what are the steps you are trying to accomplish. Can you please add to your question a bit more details? What is your setup, what exactly did you do? More details, more chance people can help you.

Comment: I want to run simple example
1. Create peers and order
2. create new channel between them 
3. Connect with Java SDK

Comment: I am having the same error, but I am in the peer directory.

Answer (score 1):

i meet the same problem. And run this command to close the network.

```
./network_setup.sh down mychannel
```

The reason that cause my problem is that the source code exists a error. So i modify this code error and reopen the network. This problem work out.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are in the incorrect working directory. When running the sample manually, you start the cli container and it places you in the `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer` directory. That is where you should be running the `peer` command. It would seem from your post that you were running the `peer` command in the `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com` directory in the container, and it is not finding the configuration files that were mounted for the example.

Comment: Even thought I mounted the right path in the volume and set the right directory as "Working directory", I face the same problem. You have any idea @christo4ferris ?

Comment: Unclear, when you exec into the container, what is the value of $PWD?

Comment: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric is the pwd

Comment: it should be the same as the working_dir value in the Compose file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer as I noted.